# After update, Ubuntu changed location of internal HD to an external media

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I'm not too sure what exactly to search to get an answer.

This morning, I installed some Ubuntu updates (I'm running 16.04) and restarted my PC. I have 3 internal drives: 1) 1 SSD @ /dev/sdb1 which has my home directory and 2) Two 2TB HDDs which were at /scratch1 and /scratch2

Suddenly, the /scratch1 HDD is now mounted as an external drive called 2.0TB Volume. The /scratch2 drive is now at /scratch1. Whilst there is now nothing at /scratch2/

Is there a quick fix to get back everything in order?

I have looked at /etc/fstab as per comments and answers and get the following:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=96e99071-17d8-410f-9ef5-33615af94f58 /               ext4         errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=79cd2a71-bd43-4ad6-92a2-9be1d8e76ed9 none            swap    sw               0       0
/dev/sdb1 /scratch2 ext4  defaults 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /scratch1 ext4  defaults 0 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  It is your machine's BIOS or EUFI that controls what drives are internal/external, and the order in which they appear to the OS (Ubuntu in this case), and not Ubuntu.  Because this can be changed by a bios/eufi setting, the /dev/sda*9* devices are not recommended instead relying on UUID or a unique ID for each drive. Did you by chance use /dev/sd? 
to refer to drives instead of the recommended UUID's ?  If so, I'd recommend switching to UUID's that don't change when you change a setting, or add/remove hardware on your machine

Comment: Thanks for the very quicky response @guiverc! Any idea which the BIOS/EUFI would suddenly changed mount locations? Honestly, I'm not very sure and I am still quite new to Ubuntu.

If this helps, the /scratch1 and /scratch2 drives are at: /dev/sdc1 and /dev/sdb1 whilst the HDD that used to be /scratch1 is now at /dev/sdd1.

I am a tiny bit confused. Should I first find a way to change the location of the new mounted HDD (get it back to /dev/sdb1) then do this UUID switch?

Comment: In GNU/Linux (Ubuntu) everything can be done in many ways; myself I prefer commands. I'd use `sudo blkid` (or if that produces a long list, `sudo blkid |grep sd`) to list your block device id's, then instead of referencing drives by sda9 or sdb9; use the UUID= unique ID's in your file system table (`/etc/fstab`).  It was what I was talking about in my prior comments, and why Emmanuel mentioned the file system tablet in his current answer.  As for why details changed; you could have plugged in a new device, your machines battery could be running low, a power spike or lots of possible reasons...

Comment: It seems as if UUID was used in `/etc/fstab` (please see my edited question!). It looks as if something happened as I'm getting `errors=remount-ro`  for 1 HDD.

Comment: You used UUID for /, but not for scratch1 & scratch2, where I thought your issue was with scratch1 & scratch2??? ie.  you didn't use UUID for the partitions that you're having trouble with... my comments were spot-on!  (*the /dev/sdb1 & /dev/sdc1 need to be replaced by their respective UUID= just like you have for you / mount*)

Comment: ps:  if your current setup isn't what you want (ie. scratch 1 & 2 are likely swapped), using the (`blkid`) command provided earlier you will likely find the UUID value for sdc1 is the value you want in place of /dev/sdb1, and UUID for current sdb1 is what you want for sdc1 - I didn't provide this as I thought self-explanatory...

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot @guiverc and Emmanuel Giftson - I've now learned something too.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the disk boot order can be defined in BIOS setting and in your case the SSD is getting booted with out any issues. Hence for the remaning two disks, I suggest you to define the mount path for each disk in fstab. Once the details are entered in fstab, though machine restarts the disk will be pointed to the mount point with out any issues.

> File Location : /etc/fstab

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my question to show the output of `/etc/fstab`.  Do I just manually enter the information in this file, then restart my machine?

Comment: Yes, do the changes and restart the machine once and you can see the mount points mounted to the corresponding drive using comment "df -h"